# AngularJS router - doesn't work the second time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vblWfhgKsBGUD8DdV0yh?p=preview) I have a ui-router `$state.goto` that only works the first time, even though I'm incrementing a `seq` variable to force the reload. See that the time stamp doesn't change. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="goto()">Go to state</button>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>
```

State HTML

```
  <div>
    {{time1}}
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$state) {

var seq = 0;

$scope.goto = function(){

    alert('about to go to state - ' + seq) ;

        var params = { 
                seq: seq++ 
               };

        $state.go ( 'state1', params );

  };
});

app.controller('state1Ctrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.time1 = new Date();

});


app.config(function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
         templateUrl: 'state1.html',
         controller: 'state1Ctrl'
    });

});
```

Comment: You are passing a parameter to your state but in your url u don't specify one.

Comment: I don't have a url, just the state name

Answer (score 4):

Since you're not actually changing state (i.e., you're hitting `state1` every time, just with a different parameter), you have to pass the third options parameter with `{reload: true}`

```
$state.go('state1', params, {reload: true});
```

Your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jpVZ5AvPnUTty8Y8yVRs?p=preview), updated

See the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) for `$state.go(to, params, options)`

**Edit** (to make this answer correct based on the comments we have below)

You aren't including the `params` in the actual state, so it's not listening for them, hence when you send them it doesn't automatically trigger a `reload`.  Your state should be:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('state1', {
    templateUrl: 'state1.html',
    controller: 'state1ctrl',
    params: {
      seq: {}
    }
  });
```

Here, the `$stateProvider` automatically sets `reloadOnSearch = true`, you could do the opposite of what you're asking by using a third parameter in your state, `reloadOnSearch: false`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid reload:true

Comment: So, your current state doesn't actually listen for any parameters (but you're passing it parameters), if it *did* listen for parameters, it would automatically `reloadOnSearch`

Comment: i was also  missing  {reload: true} it saves my live thank you

Answer (score 0):

The **params** keyword is missing, needs to be declared in $stateProvider when you use parameters:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
         templateUrl: 'state1.html',
         params: { 'seq': null },
         controller: 'state1Ctrl'
    });
```